# Доступ к классам в корневой папке проекта

Tags: java, package

Имеется стандартная архитектура Maven проекта. В папке src/main/java у меня есть класс Guy. И в этой же папке есть пакет girls, в котором есть класс SomeGirl.

Вопрос: как я могу получить доступ к классу Guy из класса girls.SomeGirl ?
Или является обязательным упаковать класс Guy в пакет (например, guys) для возможности его импортирования в класс girls.SomeGirl (import guys.Guy;)?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `import` ..

Я бы написал пример но незнаю как у вас лежат папки..

```
import com.package.girls.SomeGirl;
```

Вместо "package" подставляете вашу папку.
Нужно импортировать как библиотеку..

Comment: Для более конкретного примера вот [архитектура](https://photos.app.goo.gl/rGBQEu3pXPuFI2Kf1) моего проекта для экспериментов.
Получается следующее, что я не могу создать экземпляр класса SomeClassForOtherTests в классе FirstClassWithMethodsForTesting. Вот никак не получается его импортировать. Лишь помогает, если упакопать SomeClassForOtherTests в какой-то пакет и тогда будет доступен импорт.